# Is there any library that can convert a circuit drawn as text to a qiskit QuantumCircuit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, circuit-construction

Does anyone know of a library to convert a parametrized qiskit circuit drawn as 'text' back to a `QuantumCircuit` or similar?

I have see [this] [1](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/21795/is-there-a-quantum-circuit-builder-package-that-allows-you-to-import-export-a-ci) question, but unfortunately I cannot determine in which format the circuit has been saved. I need to start of a file in which the drawn circuit has been saved as text like this:

```
              ┌────┐    ┌────────┐ ┌──────────┐┌───┐ ░ ┌─┐
   q_0 -> 1 ──┤ √X ├────┤ Rz(3π) ├─┤ Rz(p[2]) ├┤ X ├─░─┤M├───────── 
            ┌─┴────┴─┐ ┌┴────────┴┐└──────────┘└─┬─┘ ░ └╥┘   ┌─┐    
... 

 meas: 4/════════════════════════════════════════════╩══╩══╩══╩═
```

In **more detail** the saved file in my case is a text file looking like this: It is a dictionary converted to a string using json. The values of the dictionary are lists of the ascii-art strings of the circuits generated by QuantumCircuit.draw():

```
{'ansatz 1':"['           ┌───┐     ┌──────────┐ ┌──────────┐┌──────────┐┌───┐      ░ ┌─┐   »\n   q_0: ───┤ X ├─────┤ Rz(p[0]) ├─┤ Ry(p[1]) ├┤ Rz(p[2]) ├┤ X ├──────░─┤M├───»\n           ├───┤     ├──────────┤ ├──────────┤├──────────┤└─┬─┘┌───┐ ░ └╥┘┌─┐»\n   q_1: ───┤ X ├─────┤ Rz(p[3]) ├─┤ Ry(p[4]) ├┤ Rz(p[5]) ├──┼──┤ X ├─░──╫─┤M├»\n        ┌──┴───┴───┐ ├──────────┤ ├──────────┤└──────────┘  │  └─┬─┘ ░  ║ └╥┘»\n   q_2: ┤ Rz(p[6]) ├─┤ Ry(p[7]) ├─┤ Rz(p[8]) ├─────■────────■────┼───░──╫──╫─»\n        ├──────────┤┌┴──────────┤┌┴──────────┤   ┌─┴─┐           │   ░  ║  ║ »\n   q_3: ┤ Rz(p[9]) ├┤ Ry(p[10]) ├┤ Rz(p[11]) ├───┤ X ├───────────■───░──╫──╫─»\n        └──────────┘└───────────┘└───────────┘   └───┘               ░  ║  ║ »\nmeas: 4/════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╩══╩═»\n                                                                        0  1 »\n«              \n«   q_0: ──────\n«              \n«   q_1: ──────\n«        ┌─┐   \n«   q_2: ┤M├───\n«        └╥┘┌─┐\n«   q_3: ─╫─┤M├\n«         ║ └╥┘\n«meas: 4/═╩══╩═\n«         2  3 ', '...}
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, why are you looking for a tool to do this?

Comment: Can ChatGPT give the result?

Comment: @forky40 I want to do a comparison of runs of an algorithm done on real quantum hardware with runs with a custom noise model in simulations. Therefore, I want to use the exact same circuits in the simulations as the ones used for the runs on hardware that were saved in this format.

Comment: @narip damn, I tried it, it works.

Comment: @qcabepsilon If storing the circuit to disk and import again is what you are trying to do, you can convert the circuit to QASM strings using `QuantumCircuit.qasm()` method and load it using `QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str()` method or `QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_file()` method. I can write a detailed answer if this is what you want.

Comment: This is in principle what I want to do. So, i would be very interested in a detailed answer. Nonetheless, it will not really solve my problem at hand right now, since I cannot determine in which format the circuits have been saved. The runs were already done by someone and I try to use them.

Comment: @qcabepsilon can you explain more what you mean by detailed answer, and why you can't determine which format the circuit has been saved? maybe provide headline of the file or more detail about what is the problem, so we can have more context to help you out.

Comment: @qcabepsilon 
maybe this can help you understand how to use 
`qasm()`: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.qasm.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.qasm    ,  
`from_qasm_str()`: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_file.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_file

Comment: With determine I mean define, not assess. The runs were already done and the circuits were saved in a certain format. I cannot change that. To use from_qasm_str() one has to save the information in the corresponding format. So, this is interesting for future runs. But the circuits I am dealing with now have been saved as textfile via json.dumps of a dictionary of the draw()n version of the circuits.

Comment: @qcabepsilon Can you post the exact content of the saved text file here? Is it just the ascii text drawing like that included in the question?

Comment: @JunyeHuang Yes, it is basically just the ascii drawing. I added a more complete example to the question

Answer (score 4):

You can try ChatGpt, this is what I got according to your text:
Note that, it doesn't work accurately every time, you can try to specify more in detail, or point out the error.
I said:

```
              ┌────┐    ┌────────┐ ┌──────────┐┌───┐ ░ ┌─┐
   q_0 -> 1 ──┤ √X ├────┤ Rz(3π) ├─┤ Rz(p[2]) ├┤ X ├─░─┤M├───────── 
            ┌─┴────┴─┐ ┌┴────────┴┐└──────────┘└─┬─┘ ░ └╥┘   ┌─┐    
... 

 meas: 4/════════════════════════════════════════════╩══╩══╩══╩═
can you convert it into qiskit quantum circuit code
```

ChatGPT reply:

````
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, execute, Aer

# Create a quantum circuit with a single qubit and a single classical bit
qreg = QuantumRegister(1)
creg = ClassicalRegister(1)
qc = QuantumCircuit(qreg, creg)

# Apply the gates in the circuit
qc.u3(3*pi, 0, 0, qreg[0])  # √X gate
qc.rz(3*pi, qreg[0])  # Rz(3π) gate
qc.rz(p[2], qreg[0])  # Rz(p[2]) gate
qc.x(qreg[0])  # X gate

# Measure the qubit
qc.measure(qreg, creg)

# Execute the circuit using a simulator
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
job = execute(qc, backend, shots=1)

# Print the measurement result
print(job.result().get_counts())

```
````

Comment: That is nice and quite impressive. But I'm rather looking for a general code, where I can give the string as input and get the circuit as a return, instead of asking ChatGPT for each single circuit.

Comment: ahh, if you are asking for saving the circuit as a string, just use qasm, other then qasm, there is also quil. But since you are using Qiskit, and qasm is more popular around different frameworks, you can just do what @JunyeHuang said.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comments, you can export `QuantumCircuit` object as qasm string or file and reload it later into `QuantumCircuit` again using the `QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_string` and `Quantumcircuit.from_qasm_file` methods.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
qc.x(0)

# export qasm string to a variable
qasm_string = qc.qasm()
qc_from_string = QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str(qasm_string)
print(qc == qc_from_string)
# Output: True

# store qasm string into a file
with open('qasm_file', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write(qasm_string)

qc_from_file = QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_file('qasm_file')
print(qc == qc_from_file)
# Output: True
```

You can find the jupyter notebook with full code and output here: https://gist.github.com/HuangJunye/02bdcd927de4aab0cfc214428fa1fdac

Do note that there are limitations of converting `QuantumCircuit` as qasm as OpenQASM2 does not support all features such as unbound parameters. Exporting to `Qobj` or `qpy` as explained in [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/21800/7474) is better because the conversion is lossless.